# Using the jQuery Validation plugin, how can I display the validation errors in my own span tag?

Tags: jquery, validation

Currently the jQuery Validation plugin is displaying an error by creating its own label tag, using the class `error`.

Is it possible for me to place a tag on the screen, and if there is an error have the error message injected into that tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a container and a wrapper element e.g

```
$("#myform").validate({
   errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
   wrapper: "span",
   submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
})
```

see the options in the [help](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)